# UWP Map Control Binding

Tags: dictionary, uwp

In my UWP application: I have a SQLite data base with some points and it's coordinates. I am using Entity Framework 7 and I want to bind the data to a map control. Since I only want to keep the coordinates in the database. I created a partial class to add the other required properties to bind to the map:

```
    //Database Fields
public partial class oFeature
{
    [Key]
    public string idRecord { get; set; }
    public string idTag { get; set; }
    public Double Latitude { get; set; }
    public Double Longitude { get; set; }
    public string ImageSourceUri { get; set; }
    public string MoreInfo { get; set; }
}

//Binding Required Fields
public partial class oFeature 
{
    [NotMapped]
    public Geopoint Location { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public Point NormalizedAnchorPoint { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public Uri UriSourceImage { get; set; }

}
```

To create the list for the binding I have the following code:

```
IQueryable<oFeature> myFeatures;
            using (var db = new fldContext())
        {
            myFeatures = from b in db.oFeatures
                         select new oFeature()
                         {
                             idRecord = b.idRecord,
                             idTag = b.idTag,
                             Latitude = b.Latitude,
                             Longitude = b.Longitude,
                             ImageSourceUri = b.ImageSourceUri,
                             MoreInfo = b.MoreInfo,
                             Location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition(){Latitude=b.Latitude,Longitude=b.Longitude}),
                             NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 0.5),
                             UriSourceImage = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/green.png")
                      };

            int recount = myFeatures.Count();

            var sourceData = myFeatures.ToList();
            MapItems.ItemsSource = sourceData;
        }
```

If I remove the location line:

```
Location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition(){Latitude=b.Latitude,Longitude=b.Longitude})
```

The code works but of course when I bind to the map I get an error because I have no locations. But If I keep the locations line I get an error at the line:

```
 int recount = myFeatures.Count();
```

I am getting the following error:
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Linq.Expressions.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Value cannot be null.

{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: constructor"}

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The code for the Geopoint seems ok. Can you check if all provided Latitudes and Longitudes are valid? Maybe something is wrong there?

Comment: Yes they are valid coordinates. I am using the coordinates to set the map viewBounds. And it is setting the map in the correct area.

Comment: I commented out the location line. Once I get my data. Convert the iQueryable to a list. Then I have to traverse all the elements to calculate the location:

foreach (oFeature item in ptList)

            {

                BasicGeoposition bg = new BasicGeoposition { Latitude = item.Latitude, Longitude = item.Longitude };

                item.Location = new Geopoint(bg);

            }


It works that way but it is very slow. Looks like the conversion to Location in the IQueryable Collection does not work. maybe someone at Microsoft can take a look.